# How do I change a core-menu content based on another core-menu selected value?

Tags: java, jsp, polymer

I've got a  JSP Page where i have two paper-dropdown menus (POLYMER). The fact is that the content inside it depends on a SQL Interrogation.

```html
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Categoria" Id="categoria" class="cat1" name="categoria" onclick=categoria()>
                        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
                            <core-menu id="cat1" class="menu"  >
                                
                                <%
                                    try{
                                                    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kothuwa?"+"user=Kothuwa&password=1234");

                                         stm=conn.createStatement();
                            
                            
                            
                                        query="SELECT categoria FROM categoria";
                                        rs=stm.executeQuery(query);
                                        while(rs.next()){
                                            %>
                                            <paper-item><%=rs.getString(1)%></paper-item><%
                                        }
                                    }catch(SQLException er){}
                                        %>
                               
                                  
                                
                            </core-menu>
                        </paper-dropdown>
                    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Now, i've got another paper-dropdown-menu.The content depends on what the user selected in the previous dropdown-menu. (I have to execute another query where the value of a column is equal to the value selected by the user, so that i can take the result of the query and insert it into the second paper-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: I know nothing about Polymer.  However, I hope this answer will be useful despite the javascript framework you use]

You need a dynamic behavior for the second combo based on the selection of your first combo.  The first combo is OK right now (however, I will make some observations on that later).  Your second combo cannot be exactly like that.  Your second combo must be populated during an onchange event fired by the first one.  You must implement some interaction with your server side - maybe a REST service returning a JSON string with the second combo contents that can be used to populate it.  The exact mechanism must be the one with which you are more comfortable or has less implementation risk given your choice of frameworks, etc.

Some comments on your code: if you intend this to work in a production environment, I strongly advice you to separate the SQL query from your JSP, in order to keep data access away from the presentation of the data.  This will make easier to make changes in your code once it is alive and producing.

By the way, it is always a bad idea to leave empty a `catch()` statement, don't matter where you put it ;)